# Looping through csv files to append together in stata

Tags: stata

I have 50 csv files I am trying to append together. They all take on the name mort*year*. They currently look like

mort70

```
year  cause  sex
1970  HA     M
1970  HA     F
```

mort71

```
year  cause  sex
1971  HA     M
1971  ST     M
```

I am currently using the following code:

```
local years "70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78"
local file "mort"

foreach file of local years {
clear
import "file_path/`file'"
keep year  cause
append 
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on a series of guesses on what the syntax might be or might do. Unravelling all the guesses would take a long answer. Here is a start.

Your code defines a local macro `file` containing text `mort` and then overwrites it in the loop. As you want the text `mort` always as the first element of a filename, and a indicator of year that differs around the loop, the filename is going to be assembled wrongly.

The first step is not to do that.

```
local years "70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78"

foreach file of local years {
clear
import "file_path/mort`file'"
keep year  cause
append 
}
```

Now your next problems include

1. There is no `import` command with that syntax.
2. You read in data and change it but never `save` the result.
3. A bare `append` isn't legal either.

At the frustrating early stage where everything is new, and if you don't have a mentor, then everything has to be looked up.